# Wordpress comments avatar

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I created a comments.php to style in my theme comments on my own.
I added a new column 'user_avatar' in the 'wp_users' table. So People can add user_avatars to their profile.

Now to the problem.

In the template I have a query,.. 
I made the code a little simple. so you get a basic idea, what is going on.

```
$global $wpdb;
$user = get_comment_author();
$user_avatar = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_avatar
                               FROM wp_users
                               WHERE display_name LIKE " . $user . " LIMIT 1");

  <div class="col-xs-9">
   <h1>
    <?php echo $user_avatar ?>
    <?php echo get_comment_author(); ?>
   </h1>
  </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3">
 <h1 class="text-right">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
   <?php printf(_x('%s', '%s = human-readable time difference', 'yey'), human_time_diff(get_comment_time('U'), current_time('timestamp'))); ?>
    <?php _e('ago'); ?>
  </h1>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12" style="margin:10px;">
 <?php comment_text(); ?>
  </div>
```

The query is not working sadly. I think it's because of $user... If I vardump $user_avatar I get NULL, if I vardump $user I get a string with the current name of the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `$global $wpdb;` instead of this use `global $wpdb;` (remove $ sign).

Replace your query with below query.

```
$user_avatar = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_avatar FROM wp_users WHERE display_name LIKE '" . $user . "' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. really bad mistakes.. still need to learn a lot of php :D!